# FontAwesome fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, font-awesome

I am using fontawesome 4.5 in my asp.net mvc project. I am facing following error on console 
[image]

I have included fonts in my fonts folder

[image]

And line the fontwesome style sheet in layout.cshtml

```
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and my font face attribute is like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I have also added static content in my web.config file under system.webServer

```
 <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />

      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
```

and also added MIME type in IIS

[image]

still the error remains . Need help to resolve this

Thanks

Comment: Tried this ? <link href="../../Content/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Its same see above question

Comment: Did you change urls in "font-awesome.min.css" file to proper location?

Comment: See edit , I have included @font-face

Comment: I have set urls like so in my css file "src: url('../../fonts/fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');" and it is working.

Here is full: http://pastebin.com/31pH37ty

Comment: I have checked in visual studio intellisense path is correct

Comment: Did you eventually end up with a valid solution?

Comment: Yes I have done some settings in IIS for MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your MIME types is incorrect.
Please changes like the following picture.

from `application/font-woff2` to `font/x-woff2`

[Setting MIME types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyC7S.png)